# .NET/React Typescript - Affordable Hosting Options

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cloud, web-hosting, cost-management

`TL;DR`: I am searching for an affordable platform to host a fullstack application in which I am still able to perform SQL statements if necessary.

I have been working on a portfolio piece for a few months now in order to get a job, I am utilizing .NET 7 Web API, React.ts, and MS SQL Server. I have been running into issues with AWS as the EC2 instances I've tried to use are unable to build my application. I suppose a more expensive instance would work, like the t3a.large (2vCPU 8Gib RAM) I will be testing tomorrow; however, this instance costs $120 a month which my "client" will not pay for so it will come out of my pockets. Are there any cheaper platforms in which I will still have access and be able to perform SQL commands after the Admin's initial signup?

Thanks.